# Return properties from subclass left joins when querying superclass in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

I have an `ICriteria` that returns properties from a superclass `Animal`.  Now I want to include in the results several properties from a subclass, `Bird`.  For other subclasses, these properties should return `null`.  I am using table-per-subclass inheritance.  Is there any way to do this without adding lots of `DetachedCriteria`?  NHibernate already left joins on the subclass tables; is there a way to project values from those joins?

**Update:** I need to be able to sort and filter on the subclass properties, and the entire query needs to support paging.

Here is my model:

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
    public int WhiskerCount { get; set; }
}

public class Bird : Animal
{
    public long WingSpan { get; set; }
}
```

Given the following tables:

```
Animal:
 Id | Name      
----+--------------
 1  | Sylvester
 2  | Tweety
 3  | Maru
 4  | Big Bird

Cat:
 Id | WhiskerCount
----+--------------
 1  | 6
 3  | 12

Bird:
 Id | Wingspan     
----+--------------
 2  | 0.5
 4  | 10
```

I want the following result set:

```
 Id | Name       | Wingspan
----+------------+-------------
 1  | Sylvester  | <null>
 2  | Tweety     | 0.5
 3  | Maru       | <null>
 4  | Big Bird   | 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = session.CreateCriteria<Animal>()
    .List<Animal>()
    .Select(a => new 
    {
        Id = a.Id,
        Name = a.Name,
        Wingspan = (a is Bird) ? ((Bird)a).Wingspan : (int)null
    });
```

Comment: I forgot to mention in the question, but I need to be able to sort and filter on the Wingspan property and page the results.

Comment: then there is no easy way i think. you can use `DetachedCriteria` or `Expression.Sql("NHgeneratedAlias.Wingspan <> 10")` and `Order.Asc(Projections.SqlProjection("NHgeneratedAlias.Wingspan"));`